# The X-files of Office 2007 - missing saved files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

There is a very serious matter reported already by multiple users that also happened to me today.

After saving and closing a file in Office 2007 (excel and word reported so far) the file is just gone. No history of any modification whatsoever. No entries of it in recent files. It's just like it never existed.

There have been 2 very clear cases in the last few days that exclude any user error or other probable things like system restore points, viruses, ransom-encryption:

1. Winword .docx file saved locally on a laptop Friday night. Monday, no trace of any changes of the file being done on Friday.
2. Excel .xlsx file saved this morning, after updating multiple sheets and saving after each one. This one was being saved on a file server, not locally. No trace of any recent version of the file. All changes since last month were gone even if the file was successfully saved every day since then.

As a good practice, I add a version number to any document and increment that when an important modification is done. Therefore, I have multiple previous versions of it.

The 2 systems are quite different: one is laptop, one is desktop. One is up to date on everything, one does not use updates at all. One is part of a domain, one is not.

The only common thing about them is that they both have Office 2007.

So basically, this is like not ever saving anything in it and closing it without saving changes, which obviously did not happen.

Comment: From your description, I trust that you used very controlled conditions to confirm that there is actually the symptom (e.g., not user error or mistaken recollection).  However, there isn't really any diagnostic information here for people to do more than guess at the cause.  If this is a documented bug or common problem, the symptom might be recognizable and there might be a known solution.  But if that's the case, you probably would have found it in your research before posting the question.  :-)  (cont'd)

Comment: (You mention it's been reported, but include no links and apparently no known solutions.)  I came across your question in the Close Votes review queue.  The problem is serious, but there doesn't seem to be enough information here to enable people to help.  Is there anything more you can add in the way of diagnostic info or research links and findings?  Did you see this Microsoft support page about Adobe Acrobat causing similar symptoms?: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/906899/word-does-not-save-changes-or-you-receive-an-error-message-in-an-offic

Comment: I have very controlled environment for my PC (second case) so that's why I think this is very serious. The only thing I did not try is disk-digging for temporary office file fragments. MS-site said Office 2007 is out of support so no help from there. As for adobe reader, I have XI installed but not using it and it's updates/services are disabled.

Comment: By now, Office 2007 probably contains more patches than original code. I ran into a situation with Outlook 2007; it reached a point where it just became unreliable and problem-prone. I never got it to function properly again. I finally gave up and switched to another application. You could try reinstalling the original version or rolling back updates (it didn't always have this problem). Consider switching to something else.  If you don't want to pay to upgrade MS Office, there are a number of free suites that are file-compatible, easy transition, and more capable than 2007.

Comment: There's a problem here...we cannot switch from Outlook because of a company-enforced security application that cannot properly decrypt documents through another e-mail client. Outlook is nearly not functional at this point in all cases of intensive usage. It was not designed to handle that much data. So we'll probably just have to switch to a newer Office version.

Comment: Your company has another problem if it deals with ANY security information, HIPPAA or PII: Office 2007 extended support (the support you have to pay extra for) ended in October 2017, more than a year ago. I understand you are not likely the one making this decision, but your company MUST upgrade to a current version of Office. Even if this is a valid and real issue exactly (or even worse) than you describe, Microsoft will not fix it.

Comment: I told them that.